# Error processing <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown>

Tags: hardhat, chainlink, chainlink-vrf

I try to create a subscription programmatically for Chainlink VRF through a script with hardhat. I go into an issue when I try to call a function related to the LINK Token :

[image]

Here is my script :

```
const {
  networkConfig,
  VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function createSubscription() {
  const chainId = network.config.chainId;
  const vrfCoordinatorV2 = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "VRFCoordinatorV2InterfaceSL",
    networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
  );

  const linkToken = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "LinkTokenInterface",
    networkConfig[chainId]["linkToken"]
  );

  /*const txTransfer = await linkToken.transfer(
    accounts[0].address,
    VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT
  );
  await txTransfer.wait(1);*/

  const txCreate = await vrfCoordinatorV2.createSubscription();
  await txCreate.wait(1);
  const subscriptionId = await vrfCoordinatorV2.getCurrentSubId();

  const txFund = await linkToken.transferAndCall(
    vrfCoordinatorV2.address,
    VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT,
    ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(subscriptionId.toHexString(), 32)
  );
  await txFund.wait(1);

  return subscriptionId;
}

module.exports = {
  createSubscription,
};
```

Note that I try to run the script on a mainnet fork so the addresses of vrf and link token are the ones from mainnet.

If you are asking yourself, the VRFCoordinatorV2InterfaceSL is a custom interface I add because I needed to retrieve the subscriptionId so I add the getCurrentSubId() function to the original VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.

If anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe the getCurrentSubId is not getting yours subscription.
The best way to get it is checking the subscriptions from you account.

Comment: No I already try to `console.log(subscriptionId)` and I get a result. It seems the error really happen on this line `const txFund = await linkToken.transferAndCall(
    vrfCoordinatorV2.address,
    VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT,
    ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(subscriptionId.toHexString(), 32)
  );`